# Why does prevInstance exist in WinMain and wWinMain if it is always NULL

Tags: c++, winapi, parameters, winmain

Since I am a beginner, it may be a very basic question. I am starting DirectX 11, and while creating my first application, wWinMain was used, and while searching for difference between WinMain and wWinMain, i came across this parameter prevInstance.

prevInstance is always null according to MSDN, and since it is always null, why does it exist (since it is logical to think that creators will not have given a useless parameter). And (quoting from the book),

> if you need a way to determine whether a previous instance of the
>   application is already running, the documentation recommends creating
>   a uniquely named mutex using CreateMutex. Although the mutex will be
>   created, the CreateMutex function will return ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS.

What is a mutex, and how to use it (a good link will be sufficient). And it looks like a method is needed to find if another instance of an application exists, prevInstance should have a pointer or reference to it, which is apparently not the case, since it is null. Why is it so, and what is the role of prevInstance?

Comment: Just because it *is* always null doesn't mean it *was* always null...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Raymond Chen's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/) is almost entirely dedicated to discussing aspects of the Windows API that are "oddities" to us today. And fortunately, he has a [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/06/15/156022.aspx) that answers this exact question:

> In 16-bit Windows there was a function called GetInstanceData. This
>   function took an HINSTANCE, a pointer, and a length, and copied memory
>   from that instance into your current instance. (It's sort of the
>   16-bit equivalent to ReadProcessMemory, with the restriction that the
>   second and third parameters had to be the same.)
>
> ...
>
> This was the reason for the hPrevInstance parameter to WinMain. If
>   hPrevInstance was non-NULL, then it was the instance handle of a copy
>   of the program that is already running. You can use GetInstanceData to
>   copy data from it, get yourself up off the ground faster. For example,
>   you might want to copy the main window handle out of the previous
>   instance so you could communicate with it.
>
> Whether hPrevInstance was NULL or not told you whether you were the
>   first copy of the program. Under 16-bit Windows, only the first
>   instance of a program registered its classes; second and subsequent
>   instances continued to use the classes that were registered by the
>   first instance. (Indeed, if they tried, the registration would fail
>   since the class already existed.) Therefore, all 16-bit Windows
>   programs skipped over class registration if hPrevInstance was
>   non-NULL.
>
> The people who designed Win32 found themselves in a bit of a fix when
>   it came time to port WinMain: What to pass for hPrevInstance? The
>   whole module/instance thing didn't exist in Win32, after all, and
>   separate address spaces meant that programs that skipped over
>   reinitialization in the second instance would no longer work. So Win32
>   always passes NULL, making all programs believe that they are the
>   first one.

Of course, now that `hPrevInstance` is irrelevant to the Windows API today except for compatibility reasons, MSDN recommends that you use a mutex to detect previous instances of an application.

A mutex stands for "mutual exclusion". You can refer to [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682411.aspx) for `CreateMutex()`. There are lots of examples of using mutexes to detect previous instances of applications, [such as this one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/mtguide_2.aspx). The basic idea is to create a mutex with a unique name that you come up with, then attempt to create that named mutex. If `CreateMutex()` failed with `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`, you know that an instance of your application was already launched.

Comment: I took the liberty of summarising the blog post so your answer would be more than just a link.

Comment: @Jon Purdy: I appreciate the edit, but I was already in the middle of quoting Mr. Chen's entire explanation so as to not lose context. :-)

Comment: All's well that ends well, I suppose. Maybe SO should have an indicator for answers that are currently being edited.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link! Really accurate answer!

Comment: Raymond Chen's blog is probably the best source of "Why is X the way it is, in Windows?", where X is something odd and strange. A lot of historical oddities are explained there, and a lot of it is good reading.

Comment: An elegant way of saying PrevInstance is a white elephant.

Comment: @JonPurdy Now the link is not accessible any more, so this quote is very useful! The only question is why they didn't drop the useless arguments when making Win32 API? I suspect its very similar to modern situation of almost all PCs being 64 bit, but still Windows supports running 32 bit programs natively without VM. I guess, for some time in the past it was the case for 32/16 bits too? That's why they still keep useless parameters? Can't it be somehow removed? It's very annoying!

Answer (score 2):

The prev instance parameter is there for 16-bit Windows compatibility. I think that was stated in the MSDN reference for WinMain, at least it used to be.